# Twilio-Ruby not able to load accounts_base.rb

Tags: ruby, rubygems, twilio

Currently trying to integrate Twilio into my rails app, however when I follow the steps to test out the gem and I run the provided script with my personal API keys I get the following "load error"

```
<internal:/Users/[REDACTED]/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:148:in `require': cannot load such file -- /Users/[REDACTED]/_base.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/twilio-ruby-6.0.0/lib/twilio-ruby/rest/accounts_base.rb (LoadError)
    from <internal:/Users/[REDACTED]/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:148:in `require'
    from /Users/[REDACTED]/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/twilio-ruby-6.0.0/lib/twilio-ruby/rest.rb:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/[REDACTED]/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/twilio-ruby-6.0.0/lib/twilio-ruby/rest.rb:7:in `each'
    from /Users/[REDACTED]/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/twilio-ruby-6.0.0/lib/twilio-ruby/rest.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/Users/[REDACTED]/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:148:in `require'
    from <internal:/Users/[REDACTED]/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:148:in `require'
    from send_sms.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

I've gone ahead and reinstalled the gem, tried changing the ruby version I was running, nothing helped.

Comment: This is a "no such file" error meaning that installation maybe incomplete for some reason, and/or buggy.

Comment: I've reinstalled the gem several times and it hasn't really remedied this.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio code requires some of its files dynamically. Specifically using [this logic](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/blob/90ac516b3246668141ff57e8560484582b1dc733/lib/twilio-ruby/rest.rb#L8):

```rb
require file.gsub(/.rb/, '_base.rb')
```

If your ruby is located in `/Users/me/.rbenv/`, that will translate into `/Users/me/_base.rbenv/` and the require fails. It is a bug that was reported [here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/issues/655) and solved [here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/commit/57d1d50f14e8d02637e1692c760ee4712ffdf4a7) a week ago. Expect the fix to be released in the next version of the gem.

Until then you could use this line in your `Gemfile` to use the code directly from Github, right at the point where the fix was introduced:

```rb
gem 'twilio-ruby', github: 'twilio/twilio-ruby', ref: '57d1d50f14e8d02637e1692c760ee4712ffdf4a7'
```

Or move your ruby installation away from a directory called `.rbenv`